# Display prompt in a shell run from Java ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, android, shell, sh, processbuilder

I run a `sh` shell process like this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
pb.command("sh");
Process p = pb.start();
```

and then I push commands into its OutputStream and read output from its InputStream.  All works fine - I have a shell.

**However** the shell has no prompt.  If I run "sh" on the device through adb, I get a prompt.  I can change the prompt using `PS1=blah`.  But when `sh` is run from `ProcessBuilder`, no prompt.

How can I make the prompt appear please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to force the shell to run in 'interactive' mode - equivalent to using `sh -i`:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
pb.command("sh", "-i");
Process p = pb.start();
```

That works, but unfortunately complains about not being able to find a tty fd.  I can live with that for now.

Comment: This might also help someone: I was running `bash -i` and did not read a prompt in the InputStream. When I switched to `sh -i` I did.